# SOAP-ERROR: failed to load external entity - cURL: connection refused

Tags: php, curl, soap

I run my server with ubuntu 18.4 with openlitespeed installed, i'm making some php code to call a web service with SOAP, however, on my production server i'm facing some issues:

There is the code i use, i also use this function on my local server and it works normally:

```
 $soapParams = array(
   'login'          => 'Name',
   'password'       => 'password',
   'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
   'trace'          => 1,
   'exceptions'     => 1, );

  $params = array();
  $client = new SoapClient('https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl', 
   $soapParams);

  $params = array( 'DataServerName' => 'NAME', 
    'PrimaryKey'=>'KEYNAME', 
   );


  $result = $client->ReadRecord($params);

  echo "response:\n" . $client->__getLastResponse() . "<br><br>";
```

it returns the following error:

```
 Exceção - SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl"
```

I tried executing curl in both my local server and my production server(the one that this error is ocorring), in my local server its responded normally, however in my production server it returned the following error:

```
 root@my-server:/# curl https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl
 curl: (7) Failed to connect to myserver.name port 8051: Connection refused
```

I looked on the /etc/hosts on my production server and it shows the following:

```
  127.0.0.1       localhost servermyserver
  ::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

I also executed the command

```
  netstat -ln | grep 80
  netstat -ln | grep 443
```

On my production server,

```
  root@servermyserver:/etc# netstat -ln | grep 443
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*                           LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
  tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
  tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
  tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*
  udp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*
  udp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*
  udp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*
  udp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*
  root@servermyserver:/etc# netstat -ln | grep 80
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*                     LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8090            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
  udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7080            0.0.0.0:*
  unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2307434806       /usr/local/lsws/admin/tmp/admin.sock.7958
  unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2308072711 /tmp/lshttpd/facsu7698.sock
```

However, when i run

```
  netstat -ln | grep 8051
```

That is the port i'm trying to connect with soap, it doesn't return anything, it seems like myserver doesn't listen to the port i'm trying to use.

I tried to run cURL with ipv4 to see if i can get some results:

```
  root@servermyserver:/# curl --ipv4 -v "https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl"
  *   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
  * TCP_NODELAY set
  * connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 8051 failed: Connection refused
  * Failed to connect to myserver.name:8051 port 8051: Connection refused
  * Closing connection 0
  curl: (7) Failed to connect to myserver.name:8051 port 8051: Connection refused
```

I also tried to run telnet:

```
  root@servermyserve:/# telnet localhost 8051
  Trying ::1...
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

However, if i try telnet to por 80, it responds normally:

```
  root@servermyserve:/# telnet localhost 80
  Trying ::1...
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  Connected to localhost.
  Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: Couple of things - when you're connecting using your local server, it seems you're talking to `myserver.name` and it's working. On production, you're still talking to `myserver.name` and it's not; and you're trying to talk to `servermyserver` using the name `localhost` and it's not. Is the SOAP server running on your production server? Where is `myserver.name` really? Is it on the same side of a firewall as your local system?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing names, all the code i put on the question was used on the production server, the SOAP server is external to my production server, is another service i'm trying to call remotely from another server.

Comment: So when you were trying to connect via `telnet`, why were you connecting to localhost? If that's not where the SOAP server is.

Comment: I saw on other questions talking about if the port is beign listened by the server might be the problem why the php function new SoapClient() is not working, since the service is beign called on the 8051 port.

Comment: It is important that the SOAP service be active and listening on the SOAP server `myserver.name`. So doing a `netstat` on `servermyserver` / `localhost` only tells you that the SOAP service is not being run locally, which doesn't matter because you're trying to connect to it on `myserver.name`. One thing to check is whether `myserver.name` resolves to the same machine when you look locally as when you look from production.

Comment: I checked if https://myserver.name:8051/MEX?wsdl is running on my local server and it returns the xml code when executed:
I forget to clarify about it but i'm using 3 defferent servers to make this test, my soap server(myserver.name), my local server(mylocalserver) that is the one that the soap code is working, and my production server (servermyserver) whose is the one that the soap code doesn't wotk

Comment: This is not really what I asked. If you `nslookup myserver.name` on your local server, and on your production server, do they both return the same IP address?

Comment: They do





root@servermyserver:/# nslookup myserver.name
Server:         1.1.1.1
Address:        1.1.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   myserver.name
Address: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx


root@mylocalserver:/# nslookup myserver.name
Server:         unknown
Address:        10.0.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   myserver.name
Address: xxx.xx.xxx.xxx

Comment: Then I am going to step aside for now. Clearly the SOAP service on `myserver.name` is not listening for connections from your production server; the problem will have to be looked at from the point of view of `myserver.name`. Perhaps there is a firewall that needs to have a port opened. But I'm somewhat hobbled in helping with this because of how little information we actually have here.